# OpenID Statistics. Show a list of sites

Tags: google-account, account-management, openid

I have a google-account.

And I use this account as openid on several sites.

how I can see list of these sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [Google Accounts](http://accounts.google.com) & click on [Authorizing Websites & Applications](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en_GB). That'll bring up a list of websites that use OpenID & what permissions are required.